# Intermittent A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)

Tags: iis

We have urls coming in from customers in the form of

http://oursite.com/foo/12345678-7488-4807-f249-2085208293f0/somefilename.xml&fileTypeId=1

These are coming from customers who have misconfigured their setups, and the `&` should be a `?`. We have URL rewrite rules that take URLs in that form and convert them to valid URLs

```
<rule name="Testing Rewrite" enabled="true">
  <match url="foo/([0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="ChannelContent/?foo={R:1}&amp;resourceUrl={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Most of the time this works fine but we're getting the unhandled exception `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)` occasionally with these urls.

Same url will sometime be fine, sometimes throw an exception.

We've considered adding the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` to the web.config, but since it's intermittent there isn't really a great way to check if this is going to fix things long term.